# decode H264 B frame without timeStamp

Tags: timestamp, decode, h.264, video-toolbox

I use videoToolBox to decode H264 and use metal to render it.

I found the B frames in the raw stream, but when I watch out the value of the callback function `presentTimeStamp.valid`, it returns false.

how I could decode h264 using videoToolBox in order without timeStamp in the raw stream?

Comment: Are you able to read the bytes of your raw stream? Do you know how to handle the Golomb coding of the bits in the stream? You need these capabilities to process the slice header and know the decoding order of your NAL units per each GOP.

Comment: You are right, i finally resolve it by read the raw stream, thank you!